# Cannot refer ImageMagickNET Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I downloaded the ImageMagickNET dll from [here](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/)
 and added as reference the file ImageMagickNET.dll from the folder "bin->ReleaseQ16" inside the .zip, the file is shown in the Solution Explorer:
[image]

But when I look at the references part in the Property Pages window of the solution the dll does not appear:
[image] and I cannot use any method or make any reference to it in my code, is like it does not exists, I have searched about this issue but found nothing, any ideas why this is happening, am I missing something?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you place the file in the folder, or did you actually add the file as a reference (right-click your project --> Add --> Reference)?

Comment: I added the reference with (project --> Add --> Reference).